# CoreAudio Multiple Effects Audio Units With MutliChannel-Mixer

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio

I'm trying to determine how to use multiple effects audio units feeding into a MutliChannelMixer using CoreAudio.

Right now I have one effect, distortion, that is working fine.  So the connection looks like this:

DistortionUnit --> MixerUnit --> remoteIOUnit

Also I have a callback assigned to the DistortionUnit and it works great.

But how do I use multiple effects units and assign them to different buses on the MixerUnit?  In particular I want to be able to apply an effect only to one audio stream and another effect to a different audio stream but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

So in this case my set up looks like this:

```
DelayUnit-------------
                      |                         
DistortionUnit --> MixerUnit --> remoteIOUnit
```

If I add a second effect with its own callback NONE of my callbacks are ever called and so there's no audio.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let's say you created two different audio nodes for your two different audio files.  So, you have Audio1, Audio2, Effect1, Effect2. 1. Connect Audio1 to Effect1 2. Connect Effect1 toMixerNode. 3. Connect Audio2 to Effect2. 4. Connect Effect2 to MixerNode. Then Connect MixerNode to your remoteiounit.

Comment: When you say connect Audio1 to Effect1 can you explain what you mean?  With the examples I've seen you normally create an effects AudioUnit (like a delay for example) and then you assign a callback to that unit where you feed it the audio samples as needed.     Are you referring to that type of setup or something else?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for late response. I'll give you an detailed answer tomorrow. Can you specifically describe what you're trying to do? By saying audio stream, is it a file or microphone input? What you gonna use the bus for?

Comment: Hi its an audio file. So what I'm doing now is loading the audio file content into a buffer and using a EQFilter audio unit with a callback that reads in the audio buffer as needed.  Then I connect the EQ filter up to Multi-Channel mixer which is connected of course to the remote IO Unit.  But I feel like there's a more efficient way to do this since I'm not using the EQ audio unit for anything except as a means to get the audio input into the audio graph for output to the speaker.

Comment: I didn't understand why you use the EQ audio unit. Are you going to apply an effect to your audio file with EQ? If so, you definitely need EQ audio unit.

Comment: The ONLY reason I'm using the EQ audio unit is so that I can assign a callback to it and feed in the audio file.  Please keep in mind that in my scenario I need to be able add effects to the stream dynamically.  So if I have a fixed unit with a callback (in this case the EQ unit which is dry e.g. not altering the audio) then I can add as many effects in the chain as I need to.  From there I can attach the "head" node (i.e. the last effects unit  in the chain) to the Multi-Channel Mixer.

Comment: Maybe add some code?